# TableRow not using setOnKeyPressed

Tags: java, javafx

So here's my problem. I have the following code in my controller's initialize(URL, ResourceBundle) function. The setOnMouseClicked will get called correctly when I click on a certain row, but setOnKeyPressed does not. What am I missing here?

```
tblView.setRowFactory(tv -> {
  TableRow<Entry> row = new TableRow<Entry>();

  row.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
      if ((!row.isEmpty()) && (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) && (e.getClickCount() == 2)) {
          openEntryEditor(row);
          e.consume();
      }
  });

  row.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent e) -> {
      if ((!row.isEmpty()) && (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)) {
          openEntryEditor(row);
          e.consume();
      }
  });

  return row;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The target node for `KeyEvent`s is the focused `Node`. This means only the focused node and it's ancestors receive the event.

However it's always the `TableView` that has the focus no matter what part of it you click. Therefore the `TableRow` which is added as descendant of the `TableView` does not receive the event.

You need to register this listener at the `TableView` and use the `SelectionModel` to retrieve the information you need.

```
tableView.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent e) -> {

    if (!tableView.getSelectionModel().isEmpty()
            && e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {

        System.out.println("edit " + tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());

        e.consume();
    }
});
```

Comment: Interesting. I was mislead by the Gui :P. I though that the TableRow had focus since it gets highlighted when clicked on or moved onto by the arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I hook this onto the table not the row...

```
tblView.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER) || event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.SPACE)){
                if(tblView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
                    //Do your stuff
                }
            }
        });
```